# Why do we need to add a vector as an argument in priority queue declaration?

Tags: c++, stl

Whenever I want to create a min-heap using a priority queue (which creates a max-heap by default), 
I need to pass a comparator and also a vector of the required type to be sorted, something like this:

```
std::priority_queue<int, std::vector<int>, std::greater<int> > pq;
```

Why do we do this? And why do we not have to the same for a max-heap implementation?

Comment: OT: I think you got min and max heaps the other way round.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because of template parameters being positional and C++ standard commitee's decision to order the containter type before the comparator type.

Just like with a function like this:

```
void foo(int a = 1, int b = 2);
```

- you can't call it specifying `b`, but not `a`.

For max-heap, you're using `std::less<int>`, which happens to be the default, therefore you can omit the container type as well.